# SqlSrv identify the connection as a Windows User

Tags: php, sql-server, windows-authentication, sqlsrv

I'm using SqlSrv to connect to a Microsoft SQL Server. So far I was struggling to get SqlSrv to work, but that's ok now. On a Windows 2012R2 machine with XAMPP (PHP 5.5.19) I'm trying to connect to the database using Windows Authentication.

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff628167.aspx) I'm using SQL Server Authentication when I'm providing UID and PWD in the connection options. So I left those options out but now the server tries to connect to the database as `Domain\ServerName` instead of `Domain\MyWindowsUserAccountName`. How can I set up the script to connect with my user credentials? Maybe I'm missing out on something obvious in the documentation...

Comment: Is the database local to the server?

Comment: No it's remote. Using SSMS I'm able to connect to the server using my windows account on my work station. It's also not a problem to create an ODBC connection on the server to the SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

According to document you should set Trusted_Connection to "yes"

Comment: This is for an ODBC connection (which also fails) because of this reason (I believe); `By default, the Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server use Windows Authentication to connect to SQL Server. It is important to notice that in most scenarios, this means that the Web server's process identity or thread identity (if the Web server is using impersonation) is used to connect to the server, not an end-user's identity.` And that's the very problem I'm trying to tackle. Suggestions how to let the server identify itself as a given Windows User?